# How can I use only one year from my dummy?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have some data with some individuals where I know their age (18-98) and which country they are from (1 = Germany , 2 = France, etc. ).

I have an other variable for which i want to see the effect eg. of 18 year old people from Germany.

With `dummy(data$age, sep='_')` and `dummy(data$sg2, sep='_')[sg2 = country]` I was able to create dummy variables for these two variables.
But while regressing, the output shows the effect now of every age and every country separate.
How can I combine 18 year olds from Germany that I see their effect on the other variable?

```
#Dummy age
x1 <- dummy(dat$age, sep='_')
#Dummy country
x2 <- dummy(dat$sg2, sep = '_')

fm <- lm(myvariable~x1+x2, data=dat)

summary(fm)

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  

x1age_18     1.547691   0.567995   2.725 0.006437 ** 

x1age_19     1.632648   0.567939   2.875 0.004047 **

x2sg2_1      0.083239   0.030118   2.764 0.005717 ** 

x2sg2_2      0.056555   0.030655   1.845 0.065063 .
```

This is what I get, bit how can i get x1age_18 & x2sg2_1 in one?

Comment: Hi. It's a good question but for Crossvalidated I believe https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: To get an interaction you can use `x1*x2` e.g. https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/supervised-learning-in-r-regression/issues-to-consider?ex=5

Comment: Thank you for your replies! `x1*x2`sounds good but my pc doesn't give me a summary. I always have to terminate the process. Maybe it is because x1 has 3.000.000+ elements and x2 close to 1.000.000. Is there a way i can specify x1 so only 18 years old are in x1? Maybe set x1 to something as `dummy <- as.numeric(age == 18)`? But it wont find the object age.

Comment: Somehow I cannot edit my comment. I found the `mydata = filter(dat, age == 18 & sg2 ==1)`function. This would work out if I can filter out all the rows with ages different than 18 and other countries than Germany. But if i run the command i get the message that the object `age` is not found. but it is clearly in the data set. Maybe you know why?

Comment: Try using `dat[dat$age == 18 & dat$sg2 ==1,]`